# How to update sliderInput on this shinydashboard?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming, shiny-server

I'm working on some shiny dashboard and I'm trying to update my sliderInput accordingly to some criteria.
Let me put you in context: if I choose "Diaria" in my "analisis_linea_marco_temporal" input, a slider appears at the bottom with a date range for 2021. Since it's conditional, the slider only shows when "Diaria" is selected. Now, suppose that condition is met and I choose 2019 and 2020, what I want is that now the slider input goes from "2019-01-01" to "2020-12-31"; if I choose only 2019, slider goes from "2019-01-01" to "2019-13-31" and so on. The only restriction is that user can't choose 2019 and 2021, if he/she wants all that period, he/she should select all 3 years.
Here's my main code:

```
años_an_linea <- factor(c("2019", "2020", "2021"), ordered=TRUE)



ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title="XXX", titleWidth = 650),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Análisis",
                         menuSubItem("Por línea", tabName = "analisis_linea"))
      )
    ),
      dashboardBody(
        tabItem("analisis_linea", "",
                box(width=9, "Análisis por línea",
                    plotlyOutput("analisis_linea_plot", height =400)),
                box(width=3, "Filtros",
                    br(),
                    tags$div(selectInput("analisis_linea_seleccion", "Línea", choices=c("L1",
                                          "L2", "L3", "L4"), 
                                         selected="L1",multiple=TRUE),  
                             style="display:inline-block; height: 45px"),
                    br(),
                    tags$div(selectInput("analisis_linea_año", "Año", choices=c("2019","2020","2021"), 
                                         selected="2021",multiple=TRUE),  
                             style="display:inline-block; height: 45px"),
                    br(),
                    tags$div(selectInput("analisis_linea_marco_temporal", 
                                         "Marco temporal", choices=c("Diaria", "Mensual"), 
                                         selected="Diaria"),
                             style="display:inline-block; height: 45px"),
                    br(),
                    tags$div(conditionalPanel(
                      condition = "input.analisis_linea_marco_temporal ==  'Mensual'",
                      selectInput("mes_analisis_linea", "Mes",
                                  choices= meses_analisis_linea, selected="Enero", 
                                  multiple=TRUE),
                      style="display:inline-block; height: 45px")
                    ),
                    br(),
                    tags$div(selectInput("analisis_linea_categoria_td_tp", "Categoría", 
                                         choices=c("Total", "Tipo de pago", "Tipo de día"), 
                                         selected="Total"),
                             style="display:inline-block; height: 45px"),
                    br(),
                    tags$div(selectInput("analisis_linea_td_tp", "", choices=c(), 
                                         multiple=TRUE),
                             style="display:inline-block; height: 45px")
                ),
                box(width=9,
                    conditionalPanel(
                      condition= "input.analisis_linea_marco_temporal == 'Diaria'",
                      sliderInput("analisis_linea_fecha_diaria", "",
                                  min=base::as.Date("2021-01-01"), max=base::as.Date("2021-09-30"),
                                  value= base::as.Date("2021-01-01"),
                                  timeFormat="%d/%m/%Y")
                    )
                )
                
                
        )     
      )
    )
  
    

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(launch.browser = TRUE))
```

I suspect I need to use `eventReactive` and `observeEvent` to achieve what I want and because of that I came with this sketch for  my `server` function but I simply don't know how to do next since this really surpasses my current skills both in `R` and `shiny`

```
selec_año_analisis <- eventReactive(input$analisis_linea_año, {
      get("años_an_linea")[c(input$analisis_linea_año)]
    })
    
    observeEvent(c(input$analisis_linea_año
                   , input$analisis_linea_marco_temporal), {
      req(selec_año_analisis())
      updateSliderInput(session,"analisis_linea_fecha_diaria")
    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
```

I really appreciate any idea, suggestion or bibliography. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you may want to consider using [dynamic UI](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-dynamic.html). Use the pair of `uiOutput()` and `renderUI` to set a date slider placeholder in the UI, then put the condition function in the server.

Here is a minimum reproducible example, I only kept the relative parts mentioned in your question. The same idea applies to other elements.

I am not sure I understand your question about the date slider, it seems to me that you can set a range from 2019-01-01 to 2021-09-30, then the user can select any time period in this range.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("analisis_linea_marco_temporal",
              "Marco temporal", choices=c("Diaria", "Mensual")),

  uiOutput("date_slider") # UI placeholder
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$date_slider <- renderUI({ # create UI

    if (input$analisis_linea_marco_temporal == "Diaria"){

      sliderInput("analisis_linea_fecha_diaria", "",
                  min=as.Date("2019-01-01"), max=as.Date("2021-09-30"),
                  value= as.Date("2021-01-01"),
                  timeFormat="%d/%m/%Y")
      }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Sorry for replying this too late. I was away from any programming task for a while. Thanks for your answer, I'll check how it works.